# Execute a JAR file with run time arguments

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have a JAR file created from Eclipse. Another developer wants to run the JAR with his given inputs. 
The process in the JAR file should keep running on the other machine and that developer should be able to provide the inputs at his will.
Is this possible?

I have created the JAR file with taking inputs from the Command Line. But this won't serve my purpose.

Comment: How should the jar file take the inputs then?

Comment: This is what my question is. Is there a way to pass the inputs, because the other developer would be passing the different inputs everytime

Comment: Well. I mean it's your program, so it takes inputs however you want, but you can do command line inputs, you could build a gui and have the inputs be entered there. If it's a web service you can hit it through the browser. Vagueness of question isn't helping you here though.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "The process in the JAR file should keep running on the other machine". Are you trying to change application parameters while the Jar is running, without restarting the application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible. If you e.g. add class with main method, then you can add many arguments, and get it from `main(String... args)` args inputs.

[JAVA Documentation says](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

> java [ options ] -jar file.jar [
>   argument ... ]

and

> ... Non-option arguments after the
>   class name or JAR file name are passed
>   to the main function...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following while executing:

```
java -jar <jarName> <ARGUMENT1> <ARGUMENT2>
```

where jarName is the jar file, followed by the arguments you want to provide.